# Condition when we can't construct a graph out of n nodes where each node has $k$ outgoing edges

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

We want to construct a graph with $n$ nodes  with each node having  k out going edges. Let us suppose that we are given number of nodes in graph as $n=5$ and $k=2$ and we want $2$ out going edge for every node. I read that  there is a condition that if  $n<2k+1$, then this can't happen or such graph can't be constructed. However i could not understand the reason.

Comment: What you say is false. For example, if you consider the complete graph with $5$ vertices, you have $n=5$ and $k=4$, with $5<2\cdot4+1$.

Comment: @will all five nodes in your graph have k outgoing edges ??

Comment: @here is one valid graph   1 2
1 3
2 3
2 4
3 4
3 5
4 5
4 1
5 1
5 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only true if we restrict that the graph is directed there can be at most one edge between two vertices. That is, if the vertex $ u\rightarrow v$ is in the graph, then $v\rightarrow u$ cannot be.

Under this restriction, the maximum number of allowed edges is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ . Since you want to have $nk$ edges in total, you obtain the constraint that $2k+1 \le n$.

Comment: If each vertex has degree $k$, then total edges in graph = $nk/2$

Comment: I read "outgoing edges" to mean outdegree.